# Store the selected items in localStorage and render it later

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a cart application. I have a json file which stores the list of menu items and I've rendered it to HTML using Javascript by creating a forEach loop and using document.createElement() and appendChild().
Now, when the user clicks on Add to Cart, I store the details of that menu item and find its price from the json file and call a helper function to calculate the final price.

**MY DOUBT:** 
I want to store the items chosen by the user in localStorage and then use the localStorage to render the Cart Details. How do I do it? Could you show me a snippet of the code which is relatable to my code. Also, I need to store the details of the image of menu-item in localStorage.

**SOME CODE:** 
store.js

```
//When "Add to Cart" button is clicked, this function is triggered
function addToCartClicked(event) {
  //Getting all the details of the pizza item that was clicked
  var button = event.target;
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-title")[0].innerText;
  var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-price")[0].innerText; //in the form of Rs. 400
  var sizePrices = document.getElementsByName("sizes"); //get all the radio buttons which have name="sizes"
  var size_price;
  for (var i = 0; i < sizePrices.length; i++) {
    //check among all the sizePrices, whether it is checked or not
    if (sizePrices[i].checked) {
      size_price = sizePrices[i].value;
      //Added break, because only one radio button ccould be selected at one time
      break;
    }
  }
  //console.log(size_price);
  var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-image")[0].src;
  price = parseFloat(price.replace("Rs.", "")) + parseFloat(size_price);
  console.log(price);
  //price = parseFloat(price.replace("Rs.", "")) + size_price;
  addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, size_price);
  updateCartTotal();
}

//utility function for addToCartClicked
//This will make sure that a new cart row is created under CART
function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, size_price) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
  cartRow.classList.add("cart-row");
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0];
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-title");
  //Putting the data
  var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${size_price}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
  cartItems.append(cartRow);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", removeCartItem);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("cart-quantity-input")[0]
    .addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
}
```

data.json

```
{
  "pizza": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tandoori Pizza",
      "image": "Images/pizza.png",
      "price": "Rs.200",
      "sizes": { "Small": 100, "Medium": 200, "Large": 300 }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Veggie Supreme",
      "image": "Images/pizza.png",
      "price": "Rs.250",
      "sizes": { "Small": 100, "Medium": 200, "Large": 300 }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm new to localStorage concept. Please show me a way I can store the selected items in localStorage and use it to render under Cart Items. Kindly note that I want to use pure Javascript for all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) storage object for the Document's origin the stored data is saved across browser sessions.

Using [**setItem()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) you can store data in browser.

Then by using [**getItem()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)  you can retrieve data from the browser.

```
var cartObj = {
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Tandoori Pizza',
  'image': 'Images/pizza.png',
  'price': '200'
};

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('cartMenu', JSON.stringify(cartObj));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var menuItemInCart = localStorage.getItem('cartMenu');

console.log('menuItemInCart: ', JSON.parse(menuItemInCart));
```

Here in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1zxbvdeL/) example, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a file like this:
config.js

```
export default {
// json goes here
}
```

then do this

```
import json form './config.js'

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
window.localStorage.setItem('cart', parsed); // sets the item in localStorage
```